# Access to buttons collection in a kendo grid - angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Im wondering, is it possible to use "hidden" only for buttons in first three rows of a grid? Im trying to hide them or delete without touching rest of the buttons in others rows. As you can see below, there is a possibility to hide all of them, or do whatever you want, but I can not find access to only one of them. Thanks

```
 template: `
      <kendo-grid
          [data]="view | async"
          [height]="533"
          [pageSize]="gridState.take" [skip]="gridState.skip" [sort]="gridState.sort"
          [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true"
          (dataStateChange)="onStateChange($event)"
          (edit)="editHandler($event)" (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)"
          (save)="saveHandler($event)" (remove)="removeHandler($event)"
          (add)="addHandler($event)"
        >
        <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
            <button kendoGridAddCommand>Add new</button>
        </ng-template>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" editor="numeric" title="Price"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" editor="boolean" title="Discontinued"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" editor="numeric" title="Units In Stock"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-command-column title="command" width="220">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-isNew="isNew">
                <button kendoGridEditCommand class="k-primary">Edit</button>
                <button kendoGridRemoveCommand>Remove</button>
                <button kendoGridSaveCommand [disabled]="formGroup?.invalid">{{ isNew ? 'Add' : 'Update' }}</button>
                <button kendoGridCancelCommand>{{ isNew ? 'Discard changes' : 'Cancel' }}</button>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-command-column>
      </kendo-grid>
  `
```

Comment: are u intrested in buttons or rows? i mean u need to hide specific buttons or just buttons in specific rows, disregarding buttons context

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that u need to hide buttons only in first 3 rows, no matter what buttons is, you can use `rowIndex` property to find required rows.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="testData" [height]="410">
    <kendo-grid-column field="title" title="title" width="190">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column title="buttons" width="120">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
            <div *ngIf="rowIndex >=0 && rowIndex < 3 && topButtonsDisplayed">
                <button>{{ rowIndex}}</button>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="rowIndex >= 3">
                <button>{{ rowIndex}}</button>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>

<button (click)="toggleTopButtons()">toggle top 3 buttons</button>
```

component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-grid',
        templateUrl: './grid.component.html'
    })
    export class GrifComponent {

        public topButtonsDisplayed: boolean = true;

        public toggleTopButtons () {
            this.topButtonsDisplayed = !this.topButtonsDisplayed;
        }

          public testData:  Array<any> = [
            { title: '1' },
            { title: '2' },
            { title: '3' },
            { title: '4' },
            { title: '5' },
            { title: '6' }
        ];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS:

```
>>> .k-grid tr:not(:nth-child(n + 4)) .k-button {
      display: none;
    }
```

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/BXTPQCidehWe6p5DxOyU?p=preview)